# Reveal password for dialog in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

I need to create a login dialog like this

[image]       [image]

image files: `eyeOn.png`, `eyeOff.png`

Requirements:

- password is shown only when we CLICK AND HOLD the eyeOn icon (even when we click and hold and drag the mouse to area outside of the dialog, the password is still shown), when we release the mouse, password is covered again.
- while password is shown, the eye icon is eyeOn. While password is covered, the eye icon is eyeOff.

I have just built the layout.

```
QGridLayout *mainlogin = new QGridLayout();

QLabel *usernameLabel = new QLabel;
usernameLabel->setWordWrap(true);
usernameLabel->setText("Username");
mainlogin->addWidget(usernameLabel, 0, 0);

QComboBox *usernameLineEdit = new QComboBox;
usernameLineEdit->setEditable(true);
usernameLabel->setBuddy(usernameLineEdit);
mainlogin->addWidget(usernameLineEdit, 0, 1);

QLabel *capslockShow = new QLabel;
capslockShow->setWordWrap(true);
capslockShow->setText(" ");
mainlogin->addWidget(capslockShow, 1, 1);

QLabel *passwordLabel = new QLabel;
passwordLabel->setWordWrap(true);
passwordLabel->setText("Password");
mainlogin->addWidget(passwordLabel, 2, 0);
QLineEdit *passwordLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
passwordLineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
QAction *myAction = passwordLineEdit->addAction(QIcon(":/eyeOff.png"), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
passwordLabel->setBuddy(passwordLineEdit);
mainlogin->addWidget(passwordLineEdit, 2, 1);
```

What should I do next? Pls help me with code snippet.

Comment: What's `LineEdit` class? A sub class of `QLineEdit`? If yes, you have to handle mouse press/release events in that sub class and set the appropriate echo mode depending on what user does.

Comment: @vahancho :Sorry, that is normal QLineEdit, i typed wrong. But if i can build a new class, i can not imagine your idea

Comment: Ok, so you have to sub class `QLineEdit` and do what I already explained in my initial comment.

Comment: @vahancho: could you pls express your idea with code snippet?

Comment: @vahancho: could you give me an example how i can set the echo mode corresponding to what users do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to add a `QAction` to the `QLineEdit`, this will create a `QToolButton` that we can obtain from the `associatedWidgets()` (it will be the second widget since the first one is the one associated with `clearButton`). Already having the `QToolButton` you must use the `pressed` and `released` signal.

**passwordlineedit.h**

```
#ifndef PASSWORDLINEEDIT_H
#define PASSWORDLINEEDIT_H

#include <QAction>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QToolButton>

class PasswordLineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
public:
    PasswordLineEdit(QWidget *parent=nullptr);
private slots:
    void onPressed();
    void onReleased();
protected:
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *event);
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event);
private:
    QToolButton *button;
};

#endif // PASSWORDLINEEDIT_H
```

**passwordlineedit.cpp**

```
#include "passwordlineedit.h"

PasswordLineEdit::PasswordLineEdit(QWidget *parent):
    QLineEdit(parent)
{
    setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    QAction *action = addAction(QIcon(":/eyeOff"), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
    button = qobject_cast<QToolButton *>(action->associatedWidgets().last());
    button->hide();
    button->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor));
    connect(button, &QToolButton::pressed, this, &PasswordLineEdit::onPressed);
    connect(button, &QToolButton::released, this, &PasswordLineEdit::onReleased);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::onPressed(){
    QToolButton *button = qobject_cast<QToolButton *>(sender());
    button->setIcon(QIcon(":/eyeOn"));
    setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Normal);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::onReleased(){
    QToolButton *button = qobject_cast<QToolButton *>(sender());
    button->setIcon(QIcon(":/eyeOff"));
    setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::enterEvent(QEvent *event){
    button->show();
    QLineEdit::enterEvent(event);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::leaveEvent(QEvent *event){
    button->hide();
    QLineEdit::leaveEvent(event);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event){
    button->show();
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
}

void PasswordLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event){
    button->hide();
    QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(event);
}
```

The complete example can be downloaded from the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/51192832).

Comment: thanks for your easy and clear solution. I have one more small question. What should I do for 1 requirement: when we hover the mouse into eyeOn or eyeOff, the mouse will be changed into a finger, not cursor any more.

Comment: I have tried myself and have same solution. Thanks for your support and have a nice day, eyllanesc! :)

Comment: May I ask you one more question? How should I update the code if I need the eye icons only appear when we hover the mouse onto the LineEdit of password OR the LineEdit is focused?

Comment: @gnase I have already added that functionality, any other extra question? I think you should be able to move forward on your own. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, I am totally satisfied and have learnt a lot from you. thanks again eyllanesc :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to make use of the `QAction` returned by `QLineEdit::addAction` you could probably use a [`QWidgetAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html) for this when combined with a suitable event filter...

```
class eye_spy: public QWidgetAction {
  using super = QWidgetAction;
public:
  explicit eye_spy (QLineEdit *control, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    : super(parent)
    , m_control(control)
    , m_on(":/eyeOn")
    , m_off(":/eyeOff")
    , m_pixmap_size(50, 50)
    {
      m_label.setScaledContents(true);
      m_control->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
      m_label.setPixmap(m_off.pixmap(m_pixmap_size));
      m_label.installEventFilter(this);
      setDefaultWidget(&m_label);
    }
protected:
  virtual bool eventFilter (QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
    {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        m_control->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Normal);
        m_label.setPixmap(m_on.pixmap(m_pixmap_size));
      } else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
        m_control->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
        m_label.setPixmap(m_off.pixmap(m_pixmap_size));
      }
      return(super::eventFilter(obj, event));
    }
private:
  QLineEdit *m_control;
  QLabel     m_label;
  QIcon      m_on;
  QIcon      m_off;
  QSize      m_pixmap_size;
};
```

Now, rather than...

```
QAction *myAction = passwordLineEdit->addAction(QIcon(":/eyeOff.png"), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
```

Use...

```
eye_spy eye_spy(passwordLineEdit);
passwordLineEdit->addAction(&eye_spy, QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
```

Seems to provide the desired behaviour.